# Can not load data when using autocomplete in Django

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

Trying to use autocomplete in Django I face the problem that I can not load my data to the desired textfield in my template. I follow the tutorial from here:
https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.3/tutorial.html

My view.py

```
class ProductAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Product.objects.none()
        qs = Product.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(product_name__contains=self.q)

        return qs
```

My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True,unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

My forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    product_name = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(),widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='product-autocomplete'))


    class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ('__all__')
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^product-autocomplete/$', views.ProductAutocomplete.as_view(),name='product-autocomplete'),
```

My template.html

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
<input id="product_name" type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" placeholder="type a product:" >

     </form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}
```

I have imported static and I checked that the db returns data when I access the /product-autocomplete/ url.

The difference from tutorial is that I want to use a textfield and not a form.

Moreover, I used the absolute path for loading jquery.js file and the problem remains.

Any idea why I can not load the product names inside my textfield in order to have an autocomplete textfield?

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed.

1st) There was a mistake of using a different form than the right one.

2nd) In my template I had to refer to a specific field of the form **{{ form.product_name }}** in order to load the data in my textfield.

```
<div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.product_name }}
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
        {{ form.media }}
```